# python adds extra quotes when processing a response from the database (convert json to string)

Tags: python, postgresql

I have sql query to postgresql database include this row

```
..(json_agg(json_build_object('id', activities.id, 'name', activities.name))::json->0) AS activity ..
```

this return me result as

```
'activity': '{"id" : 1, "name" : "basketball"}'
```

so values of activity key id string, how to get this format
`'activity': {"id" : 1, "name" : "basketball"}`  ?

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.3 (Ubuntu 13.3-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

p.s.
Full query

```
SELECT events.id, events.title, events.creator, events.content, events.status, \
           (jsonb_agg(json_build_object('city', locations.city, 'street', locations.street, \
           'building', locations.building, 'lat', locations.lat, 'long', locations.long))::json -> 0)AS location ,\
           (jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', activities.id, 'name', activities.name))::json -> 0) AS activity \
           FROM events  JOIN locations  ON events.location_id=locations.id \
           JOIN activities  ON events.activities_id=activities.id \
           WHERE events.id = 2 GROUP BY events.id
```

this return me

```
   result =  <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fcf16399290>
```

after I converting this to python dict object

```
 dict(result)
```

and got

```
{'id': 2, 'title': 'Test', 'creator': 1, 'content': 'Test Content', 'status': 'OPEN', 'location': '{"lat": 53.8498155, "city": "Minsk", "long": 27.4760262, "street": "Lenina ", "building": "1"}', 'activity': '{"id": 1, "name": "basketball"}'}
```

Comment: I can't see the difference between what you get and what you want. Both are just the same

Comment: the value of first example return as string `'{"id" : 1, "name" : "basketball"}'` . format that I need - json obj or smth the same `{"id" : 1, "name" : "basketball"}`  without quote `''`

Comment: when i run `select json_agg(json_build_object('id', 1, 'name', 'basketball'))::json->0 AS activity` i get this `{"id" : 1, "name" : "basketball"}`. I have no quotes around

Comment: It's strange, I don't know why I have it like that.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that when I using `::json->0` the database returns a json object ? And there is no error in syntax? Then maybe the conversion happens in my code in a different place

Comment: I don't understand what you want to exactly, but if you run `select json_agg(json_build_object('id', activities.id, 'name', activities.name)) AS activity`, you should get the expected values. ::json is a shortcut to cast a value as json object.

Comment: I added new information to the question

Comment: I think that it's the dict() function add single quotes to your json result. What is th content of result befor adding it to your dictionnary ?

Comment: I cant read result before converting it to dict. Get only database object as `<databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fcf16399290>`

Comment: If you can't have the values of your result it will be diificult to help more.

Comment: So, I think that if postgresql sintax is right, I will have to do some extra cleaning with python. what I wanted to understand is on whose side the problem is.

Comment: in your query you can remove ::json they're unusefull because json_agg return a json object. It's strange because you are using jsonb then cast it to json. Use json_agg instead of jsonb_agg